# How to build an histogram in R filling the bars with several columns binary coded?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am pretty new to ggplot2 and I would like to draw a histogram of the number of articles published per year (or 5 years) for a systematic review. I have a df like that:

```
Df <- data.frame(   name = c("article1", "article2", "article3", "article4"),    
date = c(2004, 2009, 1999, 2007),   
question1 = c(1,0,1,0),   
question2 = c(1,1,1,1),   
question3 = c(1,1,1,1),  
 question4 = c(0,0,0,0),   
question5 = c(1,0,1,0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) 

ggplot(Df, aes (date))+   
geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, color= "black")
```

Plus, for each bar of the histogram, I would like to fill the bars with the number of articles that covered a particular type of question (question 1 to 5, coded 1 or 0 depending on if the question is present or absent).The thing is I have 5 questions I would like to make visible in one diagram. And I don't know how to do that...  I tried the fill argument and to do it with a geom_bar but failed.

Thanks so much in advance for your help

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: So sorry, better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way. It's a simple bar plot with `ggplot`.
This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

t %>%
  select(-Code) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Question"),
    names_to = "Question"
  ) %>%
  mutate(Publication_date = factor(Publication_date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Publication_date, fill = Question)) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Publication Date")
```

[image]

### Test data

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- 200
Code <- paste0("Article", 1:n)
Publication_date <- sample(2000:2020, n, TRUE)
Question <- replicate(5, rbinom(n, 1, 0.5))
colnames(Question) <- paste0("Question", 1:5)

t <- data.frame(Code, Publication_date)
t <- cbind(t, Question)
```